# SignalR in asp.net website asmx project possibility?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, signalr

I'm new to signalR hope someone here can point me the way before I dive into it.
I've got an asmx asp.net website (4.5). 
I have running applications (ios/android) that are consuming it,
I want to improve my chat mechanism and after short research I've came into the SignalR.

My question is if I can work in the same website with both signalr and asmx webservies without interfering.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

SignalR provides a "hub" which you can place in your asmx page. This hub then provides a connection to the server to send and receive SignalR events.

I recommend that you get started by checking out http://signalr.net/ and play with some samples there.

Comment: Thanks it's exactly what I'm doing :)